# SMLNJ: Merging a repetitive case expression and matching part of a constructor name

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have 2 question regarding writing patterns for constructors:

1. I want to merge two patterns of constructors into one, so I wouldn't have to write the same expression over and over again.
2. I want to match a part of constructor with a pattern (I believe it's not possible but worth a shot)

A simplified example:

```
datatype X = A | CA | CB | D;
fun foo A = "A"
| foo CA = "A"
| foo CB = "A"
| foo _ = "else";
```

I would like to write a pattern something like this: `A orelse C_ = "A"` (preferably even to find a way to extract the value caught by the underscore).

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: To catch the value caught by the underscore, simply change the underscore to a variable name and the value will be bound to it.

Comment: That is not my question. The problem is to break a constructor name.
The other problem is to merge two cases into one like there using orelse in an if statement

Comment: No, you can't "pick apart" identifers. This ain't Lisp ;-). But you can condense your example into two lines by matching `D` first, then `_`. Your original isn't that simple, is it?

Comment: It is for this example, but in the original problem it won't work (this question is only a simplification of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SML/NJ supports so called [or-patterns](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/features.html):

```
datatype X = A | CA | CB | D

fun foo (A | CA | CB) = "A"
  | foo _             = "else"
```

That's the most you can do, though. There's no feature to partially match a `datatype` constructor name, i.e., your `C_` syntax.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.I already submitted the homework but good to know there is a solution for that

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this but I believe it's not really useful..

```
datatype Y = CA | CB
datatype X = A | C of Y | D

fun foo A = "A"
  | foo (C a) = "C"
  | foo _ = "else"
```

Comment: Nice try, but I'm not allowed to break the datatype (this problem originated from my homework...)

Comment: I thought so :) I don't think what you are asking is possible, but if you do find a way, please, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of that resembles merging two patterns in SML, without changing the datatype as Spela suggested, is this:

```
datatype X = A | CA | CB | D;
fun foo A = "A"
  | foo (x as CA) = bar x
  | foo (x as CB) = bar x
  | foo _ = "else";

and bar x = "A"
```

This is simply to avoid repeating the function body of the CA/CB case. In case they have common parameters that should be handled in the same way, this is also an opportunity to parameterize `bar` with the parts of the patterns they have in common.